# How to write 'utf-8' to a new CSV file using python3 with Anaconda?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, utf-8, writetofile

How to write 'utf-8' to a new CSV file using python3 with Anaconda?

I'm a new python and pandas learner. The version I use is python3. I run it with Anaconda platform, an IDE as similar as PyCharm IDE.

I have two arrays to record all words and their frequency from a long text. All the word is kept in form of string which include 'utf-8' character:

```
value = [13, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] 

key = ['-', 'Span', 'Found', 'Not', '404.0', '详细', '8.5', 'IIS', 'Details', '错误', 'Machine,', 'K', 'Ltd.', 'Co.,', 'Contact', 'Group', 'Large', 'qinwomachine', 'Trading', 'Qinwo', 'Shanghai', 'Manufacturer', 'Machine', 'Super', 'Abm240', 'Abm120', 'Mic240', 'Mic120', 'Forming', 'Roll', 'wubianstar', 'Electrical', 'Hont', 'China', 'tileformer', '\ufeffContact']
```

Now I'm trying to write those value and key array to a new CSV file called split_word.csv using python3 with Anaconda. My code is as follows:

```
# read the arrays as dataframe, also set the column name 'word' and 'frequency'
df = pd.DataFrame({"word" : newkey, "frequency" : newvalue}) 

# write dataframe into a new csv file
df.to_csv("split_word.csv", index=False)
```

My expected result in the csv is two new columns:

```
frequency   word
13          -
4           Span
3           Found
3           Not
3           404
3           详细
3           8.5
3           IIS
3           Details
2           错误
2           Machine,
2           K
2           Ltd.
2           Co.,
2           Contact
```

But there's something wrong with the actual result. '详细' and '错误' are missing:

```
frequency   word
13          -
4           Span
3           Found
3           Not
3           404
3           ????
3           8.5
3           IIS
3           Details
2           ????
2           Machine,
2           K
2           Ltd.
2           Co.,
2           Contact
```

So the only problem is the 'utf-8' input. Should I add decode or encode into the code? How can I solve the simple but annoying problem?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to specify the encoding:

```
df.to_csv("split_word.csv", index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: @HavenShi I don't know what else to do, sorry. I tested on my system and it fixed the problem. Python 3.6, Anaconda, Windows 7, and viewed the CSV in notepad++

Comment: emmmm, it seems I can do nothing lol. Although I also tested Python 3.6, Anaconda...

Comment: @HavenShi I'm also using pandas v0.20.1